# Removing Extra "" from JSON values in using scala

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have been trying to clean my JSON object using scala but I am not able to remove extra "" from my
JSON value
example "LAST_NM":"SMITH "LIBBY" MARY"

Extra commas inside my string are creating problem.

Here is my code that I am using to clean my json file

```scala
val readjson = sparkSession.sparkContext.textFile("dev.json")
    val json=readjson.map(element=>element.replace("\"\":\"\"","\":\"")
   .replace("\"\",\"\"","\",\"")
   .replace("\"\":","\":")
   .replace(",\"\"",",\"")
   .replace("\"{\"\"","{\"")
   .replace("\"\"}\"","\"}")
   .replaceAll("\\u0009"," "))
   .saveAsTextFile("JSON")
```

Here is my json string that I want to clean (whitespace added for readability):

```
{
  "SEQ_NO":597216,
  "PROV_DEMOG_SK":597216,
  "PROV_ID":"QMP000003371283",
  "FRST_NM":"",
  "LAST_NM":"SMITH "LIBBY" MARY",
  "FUL_NM":"",
  "GENDR_CD":"",
  "PROV_NPI":"",
  "PROV_STAT":"Incomplete",
  "PROV_TY":"03",
  "DT_OF_BRTH":"",
  "PROFPROFL_DESGTN":"",
  "ETL_LAST_UPDT_DT_TM":"2020-04-28 11:43:31.000000",
  "PROV_CLSFTN_CD":"A",
  "SRC_DATA_KEY":50,
  "OPRN_CD":"I",
  "REC_SET":"F"
}
```

What should I add in my code to remove extra "" from LAST_NM value of my json string.

Comment: can you add expected output if possible ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check below code

```
df.map(_.replaceAll(" \""," ").replaceAll("\" "," ")).show(false)

+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|value                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|{"SEQ_NO":597216,"PROV_DEMOG_SK":597216,"PROV_ID":"QMP000003371283","FRST_NM":"","LAST_NM":"SMITH LIBBY MARY","FUL_NM":"","GENDR_CD":"","PROV_NPI":"","PROV_STAT":"Incomplete","PROV_TY":"03","DT_OF_BRTH":"","PROFPROFL_DESGTN":"","ETL_LAST_UPDT_DT_TM":"2020-04-28 11:43:31.000000","PROV_CLSFTN_CD":"A","SRC_DATA_KEY":50,"OPRN_CD":"I","REC_SET":"F"}|
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```